# ¿Cómo realizar correctamente un Pivotado Dinámico de dos columnas parametrizado por un tercer campo de rango de fechas?

Tags: sql-server

**Procedimiento que pivota 2 columnas y que dependen de rango fechas**

Creo el procedimiento con rango de fechas desde-hasta

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr1]
@fechaDesde date, @fechaHasta date AS  BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Creo tabla temporal previa al pivotaje:

Los campos fijos en filas seran campo1, campo2, fecha
Los campos a pivotar posteriormente seran codigo, total

```
CREATE TABLE #TOTALES (
  IDENTIF INT NOT NULL,  CAMPO1 INT NOT NULL,  CAMPO2 INT NOT NULL,  FECHA DATE NOT NULL,  CODIGO INT NOT NULL,  TOTAL  INT NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (IDENTIF), UNIQUE (IDENTIF) );
```

Inserto varios valores, pero hay que fijarse que en el id 1 de fecha 1 de mayo tiene el mismo codigo (100) que el dia 2

```
--DIA 1
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (1,111,112,'2021/05/01',100,10 ); 
--DIA 1
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (2,211,212,'2021/05/01',150,15 ); 
--DIA 1
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (3,311,312,'2021/05/01',200,11 ); 
--DIA 2
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (4,411,412,'2021/05/02',500,30 );  
--DIA 1
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (5,511,512,'2021/05/01',300,29 ); 
--DIA 1
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (6,611,612,'2021/05/01',180,66 ); 
--DIA 2
INSERT INTO #TOTALES (IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO, TOTAL) VALUES (7,711,712,'2021/05/02',100,99 );
```

Creo otra tabla temporal para extraer un rango de fechas introducidas por parametro

```
SELECT #TOTALES.*   
INTO #TOTALES_FIN   
FROM #TOTALES   
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN @fechaDesde AND @fechaHasta;
```

Hago el pivotado, aunque esto es un ejemplo simple, en mi proyecto, (por eso lo hago dinamico) no se cuantas columnas codigo va a mostrar

```
DECLARE @sprdElements AS NVARCHAR(MAX)        
        ,@tSql1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)       
        ,@CODIGO VARCHAR(255);     

WITH dsitSpreadElList AS
```

He probado con y sin DISTINCT por si fuese ese mi problema aparentemente no lo es

```
(SELECT distinct IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, CODIGO  FROM #TOTALES_FIN )

SELECT @sprdElements = COALESCE(@sprdElements+', ','')+'['+ CAST( CODIGO AS NVARCHAR(255))+']'  FROM dsitSpreadElList;
 
SET @tSql1 =N';WITH TabExp AS
             (SELECT IDENTIF ,CAMPO1 ,CAMPO2 ,FECHA
                      ,CODIGO      -- spreading element
                      ,[TOTAL]     -- aggregating element
                FROM #TOTALES_FIN   )

             SELECT IDENTIF,CAMPO1, CAMPO2, FECHA, '+@sprdElements +N'
             FROM TabExp
             PIVOT (
                    sum([Total])
                    FOR CODIGO IN (' + @sprdElements +N') 
                    ) AS pvt'
 
 EXEC sys.sp_executesql
     @stmt = @tSql1
END
```

Ejecutando el Procedimiento :

---

Cuando el rango de fecha es de un solo dia (en este caso, el dia 1) no hay problema, salen todos los datos  :

```
exec [pr1] '20210501','20210501' ; 
GO
IDENTIF CAMPO1  CAMPO2  FECHA       100     150     200     300     180
1       111     112     2021-05-01  10      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2       211     212     2021-05-01  NULL    15      NULL    NULL    NULL
3       311     312     2021-05-01  NULL    NULL    11      NULL    NULL
5       511     512     2021-05-01  NULL    NULL    NULL    29      NULL
6       611     612     2021-05-01  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    66
```

Cuando el rango de fecha es de más de un dia :

```
exec [pr1] '20210501','20210502' ; 
GO
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 108   The column '100' was specified multiple times for 'pvt'.
```

Aquí no he visto la forma de poder recrearlo, pero en mi caso real ocurre también lo siguiente, y es que no me da este error
pero en cambio, únicamente me visualiza las columnas CODIGO que coinciden en el día 1 y día 2, es decir, algo así

```
IDENTIF CAMPO1  CAMPO2  FECHA       100
1       111     112     2021-05-01  10
7       711     712     2021/05/02  99
```

Answer (score 0):

En teoría, deberías de tener una tabla de códigos para tomarlos de ahí, pero en este caso asumiré que no existe.

El problema está en que estás repitiendo los códigos al momento de formar la cadena en @sprdElements. Eso se puede solucionar dejando únicamente la columna que quieres que sea única.

```
WITH dsitSpreadElList AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            CODIGO  
    FROM #TOTALES_FIN 
)
SELECT  @sprdElements = COALESCE(@sprdElements+', ','')+'['+ CAST( CODIGO AS NVARCHAR(255))+']' 
FROM dsitSpreadElList t;
```

De la forma en la que lo tenías, generaba filas únicas de acuerdo a todas las columnas, pero tú solo necesitas valores únicos de la columna CODIGO.

#### Detalles adicionales:

- El punto y coma es para terminar instrucciones (como en otros lenguajes) no para iniciarlas.
- Si una columna está como PRIMARY KEY, no es necesario agregar una constraint UNIQUE.

Comment: Era eso, Muchas gracias. Y ¿Se puede hacer un doble o triple pivotado? Es decir, códigos comunes y 3 sumatorios totales , cada uno de su tabla para poder visualizar algo así  :                                                                                                                   codigo suma1 codigo suma2 codigo suma3                                                                         1          10        1           20       1          30                                                                            2           5         2           7         2          14

Comment: Se puede hacer, pero aconsejo que en ese caso se cambie el pivot a un agregado condicional. Es más flexible y obtiene un mejor rendimiento cuando las consultas empiezan a ser más complejas.